# In a UWP application, is it possible to access Bus 0

Tags: c#, camera, uwp, windows-10-universal, hid

I'm porting over functionality from our legacy Silverlight application to our new UWP application and running into a problem with some Human Iterface Device (HID) code.  We're using a camera with a button and need to take a picture when the button is clicked.  In SilverLight we were able to connect to the camera using HID, but when i try the same thing in UWP I'm unable to make the connection.  After debugging the problem, the camera is using Bus 0 and the UWP platform blocks access bus 0.  I'm able to run legacy applications on Windows 10 and still access the camera's button so the problem resides in UWP blocking access to bus 0.  Is there a work around to access Bus 0?  Here are some additional details:

- We’re trying to access the camera (a ProScope microscope) in our Windows 10 Universal Application (UWP) written in C#
- We’re using the HID class libraries built into .NET to access the scope
- UWP requires that we declare that the application needs access to HID resources (here’s an example in the Package.appxmanifest):
- When I add the configuration above, I get the following error:

DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. The Appx package's manifest is invalid.: Cannot register package because of a problem with Function element usage:0000 *: Value is blocked, and not allowed on this bus (0x80073cf6)

- When I look in the Device manager for the camera (ProScope) under the HID section, it says it’s running on bus 0 and I've confirmed with the hardware vendor it is in fact running on bus 0 and they currently don't have a good way to change this.
- Here are a couple of links related to bus # 0 being blocked:

  - https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1b2ebdee-4f60-4567-b9ac-9306b44b94a0/specifying-usb-hid-usage-page-0x000c-causes-value-is-blocked-and-not-allowed-on-this-bus?forum=tailoringappsfordevices
  - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.humaninterfacedevice.aspx